# Setting secret questions and answers for users in Orchard CMS

Tags: security, orchardcms

I would like to have the user registration be a little more secure by adding security questions. I could create a new contentpart and attach it to user contentitem. But before I do that I would like to know if its not already there.

Comment: It's definitely not in Orchard by default.  I haven't seen a module in the gallery for it, but that's not to say it isn't out there somewhere.  Sounds like a good idea to go ahead and build it to me.

Comment: Do you mean a [Captcha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA)?

Comment: No, not a captcha. This is for password reset. Before a password is reset, you need to answer the secret questions, like What is your favorite pet.

Comment: "Security" questions and answers generally don't add any security; I call the insecurity questions.

Comment: What is in your opinion the best way to support password resets. I remember reading that questions are ok. As long as you dictate the questions. So please provide more comment than that its not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [extended registration module](http://extendedregistration.codeplex.com/) and add the security questions there - I am using this module to capture other user information and it works great.  However my workflow is such that an admin creates users....so this might be different from your workflow where the user will be entering their own registration info.